# How to run same migration file on same db multiple times in laravel?

Tags: laravel, migration

I am working on a laravel project with multiyear data. For multiyear db management i am using partitioning. One table(with data) is needed to migrate every year with some modification in data. I have written up/down in migration for the same.
But problem is if i run migrate command once, same migration file can not be executed for next year. It gives response -'Nothing to migrate'

Comment: make new migration file for the changes

Comment: create a new migration to executing what you want

Comment: I think you need to run seeds if you only want to modify data in table(not table structure itself). you can create task which will run seeds after specific period. but if you want to modify table, you have to create new migration

Comment: I am working on school product which is used by 100 schools. At every new academic year, previous year's students needed to promote to next year with changes in some fields. It is not easy to create new migration file every year for 100 schools. And it may require for more than one table.

Comment: read about database seeding https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding and tasks https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling

Comment: If you are not changing the tables structure and the tables have the same name, what are you migrating? Are you sure what you want is migrating, and not seeding?

Comment: @Amarnasan i want migrating and seeding both. migration to add new partition to table every year. n seeding to add/modify data.

Comment: I'd use commands for that. Not Migrations. You can add Table migrations to your command and seed function aswell

Comment: But what is a partition?

Comment: Partitioning reduce the cost of storing large amounts of data. Can be achieved without splitting tables by physically putting tables on individual disk drives. Partitioning allows tables to be subdivided into smaller pieces, therefore queries that access only a fraction of the data can run faster because there is fewer data to scan.

Comment: Use github or bitbucket for making changes on project and name branches after year or something similar. Then use latest branch.

Comment: Why dont you create a cron job that iterates for each student. @charu  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling